# no carbonation and a few bottle-bombs

Tags: carbonation, bottle, bottle-bomb

I bottled about a month and a half ago.  Every bottle I tried has had no carbonation.  But I just opened up a bottle and it was over carbonated, and it almost exploded out of the bottle.  I had this problem with another batch last year.  Almost all the bottles had no carbonation but I had a few bottle bombs.  Could it be that the priming sugar didn't mix enough in the bottling bucket and it all just went into a few bottles?

Comment: It does sound that way, yes. How are you adding your priming sugar?

Answer (score 5):

It does sound like your priming sugar wasn't mixed very well. That said, if the flat bottles are sweet to the taste there's something else afoot.

When I bottle I usually mix a cup of water with 3/4 cup of corn sugar and stick it in the microwave for a couple minutes to boil it. I then let it cool for a while before pouring the solution into the bottom of the bottling bucket before racking the beer. After that, I gently stir the sugar into the beer with the auto-syphon before filling any bottles.

Comment: Thanks, how long do you let it cool? I boiled my sugar on the stove and let it cool for about 1/2 hour and dumped it in the bottling bucket.  When I siphoned the beer to the bottling bucket I didn't mix it with the siphon, I just siphoned it in the bottling bucket and racked it.  I'll be more careful next time.